# How can I get synsets related to a reference synset via also-see and similar-to relations? (Python NLTK)

Tags: python, nltk, wordnet

The following code uses a seed positive word and adds all of its synonym members (lemmas) to a list.

```
from nltk.corpus import wordnet as wn

def pos_expansion():

pos_list = ['good'] #positive seed list
lemmas = [] #list of lemmas
unique_lemmas = []

for pos_word in pos_list:
    for synset in wn.synsets(pos_word):
        if synset.pos() in ['a', 's']: #restrict synsets to adjectives only
            lemmas = lemmas + synset.lemma_names() #add all synonyms (lemmas) within each synset of pos_word

print(lemmas)

pos_expansion()
```

I want to do the same, but with synsets. I want to return a list of actual synsets based on the also-see, similar-to and attribute relations in NLTK's WordNet (assuming the seed synset is 'good.a.01'). Is this possible? Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Synsets have different relations that individual terms in WN. Synset relations required are as follows:

```
    for i in wn.all_synsets():
        print(i._related('n'))
        print(i.also_sees())
        print(i.similar_tos())
```